# Alternative STL implementations in C++11 and beyond

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Over time various alternative implementations of the STL* have appeared - such as STLPort.  Certain large corporations also use their own internal port of the STL for various purposes.

With C++03, it's possible to write a port of the STL using only portable C++ language features, meaning that any conforming compiler should be able to compile it.

But with C++11, aren't there certain features which require *compiler* support?

For example, I don't see how `std::is_standard_layout` could be implemented using only C++ language features.  I think `std::is_base_of` could be implemented in terms of `std::is_convertible`, using base and derived pointers.  But I can't imagine how `std::is_standard_layout` could be implemented.  There may be other features as well which haven't occurred to me.

So, am I correct here?  Is it impossible to write am complete port of the standard library in C++11 using *only* C++ language features?

*I know STL and "C++ standard library" are not strictly interchangeable, but obviously I mean the C++ Standard Libary in this case.

Comment: How would one rewrite e.g. `std::set_terminate` in C++03? And what about `new` and `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: What is the difference between features which require language support and those which require compiler support?

Comment: `new` is a language feature, not a library feature.  but you have a point I think about `std::set_terminate`

Comment: Who cares? You can't write a standard C library implementation without compiler support either.

Comment: As per the spec, an implementation consists of **compiler + library**. That tells us lots of things.

Comment: I don't think `std::is_standard_layout` is part of *Standard Template Library*.

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't write a fully portable standard C++ library implementation in any version of C++! FIrst of all, some standard C++ library components clearly abstract the system specifics. For example, the file streams abstract the access to file access. Yes, you could use `FILE*` under the hood but I consider the standard C library to be part of the standard C++ library and a portable implementation would need to include that portion as well. Also, certain types are actually depending on the compiler, e.g., because there is language level interaction with them. For example `std::bad_cast` is thrown as a result of a `dynamic_cast<...>()`. Also, some standard C++ library components need to make use of knownledge about the memory layout and that `reinterpret_cast<...>()` does the Right Thing. In other cases, the standard library specifies values which cannot be determined portable, e.g., some of the fields of `std::numeric_limits<T>`.

The overall idea of the standard C++ library is that it covers common needs and implements certain features which can't be implemented portably and efficiently. The type traits you quoted are just some of the examples where compilers need to provide some help. Although I tried to get some agreement on how the type traits are exposed by the compilers, the compiler writers insisted that they need to be free on their choices and that the standard C++ library should just give a common interface to the way the traits are exposed.

Comment: @DyP: yes. I'll fix it. Thanks!